# How can I prevent EndpointServlet objects from being sent to SimpleMessageConverter in Spring Cloud Stream with RabbitMQ?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-actuator, spring-rabbit

spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit 2.3.6.RELEASE

I have spam errors when my application is starting. It does not stops the app but it pushes a lot of error messages in logs.

```
2023-06-03 20:07:13.713 [,,][scheduling-1] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@70679116]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SimpleMessageConverter only supports String, byte[] and Serializable payloads, received: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointServlet, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointServlet@19e0b41b, headers={b3=77cb3b12785f18e4-03c9c17283a9e26b-1, nativeHeaders={b3=[77cb3b12785f18e4-03c9c17283a9e26b-1]}, id=6ac6a76c-5f42-2219-1721-37c7b5781e2a, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1685812033712}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.doSend(AbstractMessageRouter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:196)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.messageReceived(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:475)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:461)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:341)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SimpleMessageConverter only supports String, byte[] and Serializable payloads, received: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointServlet
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.createMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:164)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.createMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder$SimplePassthroughMessageConverter.createMessage(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.createMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.MappingUtils.doMapMessage(MappingUtils.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.MappingUtils.mapMessage(MappingUtils.java:59)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.doRabbitSend(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:247)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.send(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.handleRequestMessage(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:180)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    ... 43 more
```

I thought that it is trouble with our dtos but when I went to the SimpleMessageConverter class and placed the breakpoint at line 133 I got the object instance of class org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointServlet. Tell me please, how can I turn off sending EndpointServlet  to converter?

Comment: How that happened that you send it there into binding at all? What the logic in your application? Looks like you have `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` which produces a message into binding with that `EndpointServlet` payload. You probably need to share much more info about your project. Or even better to share some simple one so we can reproduce it locally. However it is still clear from that stack trace that your inbound channel adapter  somehow sends a message with an `EndpointServlet`.